# Using a Switch statement to count emoticons in a Twitter Search API? Java

Tags: java

I have looked to see if anyone else has asked this question or if there is a similar type question, but i could not find any.

I have created code to access the Twitter Search API. I am able to access Twitter, and get back some Tweets. 
However i am supposed to create an application that counts emoticons. I have created a Switch case statement, that lists all the emoticons that I want the search API to pass through and i want a count of them. And if it passes a emoticon and it is in the tweets, i want it to count it. 
I have over a 100 emoticons, I have separated them in their own switch case statement. 
How do I get count the emoticons the emoticons that may have showed up in the tweets?? In java please. Or can you please advise me on an alternative route.

ok cool

Here is my Twitter Search API code:

```
  public class searchingTwitter {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String urlstr = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=";
    // that is the Twitter search API, i can request a search query and get tweets related to query
    StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
    System.out.print("Search for : "); // this is where you input what you want the tweets on
    urlstr += in.readLine();
    URL url = new URL(urlstr);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openConnection().getInputStream()));
    // opens a connection to twitter and gets the tweets
    int c;
    while ((c=br.read()) !=-1) { // stores the tweets
        buff.append((char)c); 
    }br.close();    

    JSONObject js = new JSONObject(buff.toString()); //converts whatever is buffered from Twitter to String
    JSONArray tweets = js.getJSONArray("results");
    // results = array, represents a single tweet and all the information regarding that tweet
            JSONObject tweet;
    for(int i=0;i<tweets.length();i++) {
        tweet = tweets.getJSONObject(i);
        System.out.println((i+5)+") "+tweet.getString("from_user") // username of tweeter
                +" at "+tweet.getString("created_at")); // time tweet written/created
        System.out.println(tweets.getJSONObject(i).getString("text")+"\n"); // Prints out the tweet texts, one on a new line everytime
}
```

How do I call the happiness class? So that it can look through and count please.

Thanks for helping me! This was for my dissertation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a map not a switch. Switches are really for small datasets with specific code snippets
to execute. For associating pieces of data maps are far better. Also prior to jdk 7 only
ints can be used for switch statements.

```
public void updateEmoticonMap(Map<String,Integer> countMap, String emoticon){
    Integer count = countMap.get(emoticon);
    if(count == null){
        count = 0;
    }
    count++;
    countMap.put(emoticon,count);
}
```

Comment: How do i add emoticons to a Map?

Comment: Any emoticon not already in the map will get added automatically. Otherwise `countMap.put(emoticon,0);`

Comment: not all of my switch statements have more than 10 emoticons, is it still worth it to use a Map? There's one with 3 in it.

Comment: Yes. Switch statements are really something that is inherited from imperical languages and of limited use. For OO and Functional style coding Collections are far more useful.

Comment: is it possible for me to call another class from my main class. The twitter one. And how do i go about doing that please?

Comment: [tutorials are a good place to start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)